# MATLAB - Need to find a statistical measure

Tags: matlab, octave

If we have the mean of a set of numbers, we can find the standard deviation. Is there a command in MATLAB, i.e., a parameter to *compare the data of a mean closed curve with the data of all* the original closed curves. I need a statistical measure **like the standard deviation**. For this case...imagine I have

```
3 2 4 
2 3 7 
4 2 3
```

the mean

```
3
4
3
```

and then some parameter like standard deviation, that is not applicable for this case of course.

Comment: well, you have `var` that behaves as `mean`, but returns variance..

Comment: uh, there is just the [std function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/std.html), why would this not be applicable?

Comment: because imagine a have a mean curve, and i need a number to charactherize this mean data i obtained

Comment: you're question still doesn't make sense to me.. what do you mean eg with 'mean (closed) curve', 'mean data', 'data of a mean closed curve' , 'data of all the original closed curves',...

Comment: imagine you have many separate circles. i got the average circle. now i want something like the stdrd deviation to characterize this mean(that here is impossible, but it must exist some parameter i cant remember). am i clear?

Comment: you're still describing the standard deviation imo, which is just applicable here, see @Squazic's answer. Yes that returns a vector of standard deviations corresponding to each row. If you want just _one_ scalar value, improvise a bit, take the max/min/mean from that vector of standard deviations. This is totally up to you, and depends on your application.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question is misleading. It seems you want the standard deviation, which is easily accomplished using the [`std`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html)

To get the row standard deviation, it's simply

```
std(A, 0, 2)
```

where `A` is your matrix, 0 is the way the stdev is calculated, and 2 means along the second dimension, which in MATLAB, is the row dimension.

Comment: no, but this is not what i mean. imagine you have 3 3 3- the mean is 3 and the SD=0. now we have the result of mean(a,2). is there any parameter like the SD or somethhing to caracterize this mean? thank you very mych

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the `mean` command will do this

```
> a=floor(rand(3)*9);   %This just creates a random matrix, it isn't important.
   a= 
     4  0  8
     7  8  0
     4  1  4
> mean(a)
ans =
     5  3  4
> mean(a,2)
ans =
    4
    5
    3
```

Note the second argument tells the system which dimension to do the mean on. The same thing should work for standard deviation.

Comment: i am sorry i didn t understand... can you explain?

Comment: Added my sample output, hope it makes sense.

Comment: no, but this is not what i mean. imagine you have 3 3 3- the mean is 3 and the SD=0. now we have the result of mean(a,2). is there any parameter like the SD or somethhing to caracterize this mean? thank you very mych